# Arc4random float?

Tags: ios, objective-c, random

Doing this:

```
float x = arc4random() % 100;
```

returns a decent result of a number between 0 and 100.

But doing this:

```
float x = (arc4random() % 100)/100;
```

Returns 0. How can I get it to return a float value?

Comment: Use `arc4random_uniform(int)` instead of a modulo construct. See the man page (`arc4random(3)`) why.

Comment: arc4random_uniform was added in 4.3. I would also use this instead of my answer below if you are able.

Comment: First line returns an int between 0 and 99.

Comment: This one only gives two digits after decimal point; for more digits use `drand48(3)`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Simply, you are doing integer division, instead of floating point division, so you are just getting a truncated result (.123 is truncated to 0, for example). Try

```
float x = (arc4random() % 100)/100.0f;
```

Answer (score 5):

You are dividing an int by an int, which gives an int. You need to cast either to a float:

```
float x = (arc4random() % 100)/(float)100;
```

Also see my comment about the modulo operator.

Answer (score 2):

To get a float division instead of an integer division:

```
float x = arc4random() % 100 / 100.f;
```

But be careful, using `% 100` will only give you a value between 0 and 99, so dividing it by 100.f will only produce a random value between 0.00f and 0.99f.

Better, to get a random float between 0 and 1:

```
float x = arc4random() % 101 / 100.f;
```

Even better, to avoid modulus bias:

```
float x = arc4random_uniform(101) / 100.f;
```

---

Alternatively, to avoid a two digits precision bias:

```
float x = (float)arc4random() / UINT32_MAX;
```

And in Swift 4.2+, you get built-in support for ranges:

```
let x = Float.random(in: 0.0...1.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift:

```
Float(arc4random() % 100) / 100
```